# Select date column by locations: #IndexingError: Too many indexers AND TypeError: cannot do slice indexing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

In Python 2.7.6 and pandas 0.17.0,

I am making time series plots. Plot the word count v.s. time. The script will read the twitter data and count how many times the word appears along the time. 
Here is an exampled pandas table,'per_minute' (the first column is 'time' and the second column is 'word count'.):

```
 print type(per_minute)

 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

 print per_minute

 2015-10-29 01:55:00    1
 2015-10-29 01:56:00    1
 2015-10-29 01:57:00    0
 Freq: T, dtype: float64
```

I am trying to select the time column (for example,"2015-10-29 01:57:00", or "2015-10-29", or "01:57:00") so I can dump this time info to matplotlib.pylot tick labels.

This scripts will read hundreds of twitter json files, so the first column will not exactly be "2015-10-29 01:55:00    1", just an example here.  But it will be in the "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss   word_count" fashion.

```
 plt.axes().set_xticklabels(dum_the_info_here,rotation='50', fontsize=8)
```

I have tried many shots:

```
print per_minute.loc[idx[1:1]] #Print: Series([], dtype: float64)

print per_minute.ix[:,0]  #IndexingError: Too many indexers

print per_minute.loc[:,per_minute ] #IndexingError: Too many indexers

print per_minute.loc[1:1] # TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [1] of <type 'int'>
```

Can any guru enlighten?  Thank you!

Comment: Does `per_minute.loc['2015-10-29 01:57']` work?

Comment: It will print out 0.0.  Also, this script will process many different files with different time, so this trick might not work : /

Comment: What trick are you referring to? You asked how to pull a specific row label value out, beyond that you need to edit your question and explain clearly what you're trying to do

Comment: The "per_minute.loc['2015-10-29 01:57']" trick

Comment: Sorry it's still unclear can you edit your question and explain why this is a problem and not as a comment

Comment: You have a `Series` not a `df` so your question is unclear when you refer to `first column will not exactly be "2015-10-29 01:55:00 1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.plot()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html) on your `Series` uses the `index` for the x axis by default and returns a `matplotlib.AxesSubplot`, on which you can `.set_ticklabels` like so:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=90)
```

Comment: Thanks! When I put "ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=90)" on, the tick labels will be misplaced (Both "2015-10-29 01:57:00" and "01:57" will exist and be misplaced).  　If I just do "ax = per_minute.plot()",  the tick looks clean and nice but I have no control of the ticks I want.  Any solution?

Comment: You can certainly vary angle, fontsize and other parameters, the 90 degree option was just for illustration - http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels. You also change the formatting of the `DateTimeIndex` using `df.index.apply(lambda x: x.strftime(desired_format)` - see for instance http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm